# Private Domain Deliverability Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain

We are having major issues with some new Private Domains when it comes to delivilibty - the biggest issue being blocked bounces that are having 'Authentication' issues. The SAP that was originally made for that MID is not experience these same issues.

The private subdomains are purchased through Salesforce so all of the needed authentication should be in place. Looking in google postmasters tool the DKIM and DMARC both get 100% success rate and the Domain Reputation is at a medium.

Salesforce is telling me that my send volume for my MID is too small for a private IP Address but that address is also used on another MID that has a very large send volume so I don't see how that could be the issue.

I think the issues lies with the SPF which success rate is always 0%. How do I fix this issue? Or is there any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar behaviour in Google Postmaster Tools (0% success rate) - it was caused by me adding the subdomain (marketing.example.com) to the Postmaster Tools. Adding the top domain (example.com) solved the issue.

An easy way of testing your PD authentication is by using https://www.mail-tester.com/ - which gives you a complete overview of the “spammyness” of your email.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I checked the authentication from mail-tester and we have a 9.3 score so in theory we shouldn't be getting blocked. While the SPF did show up as valid for all the private domains but one error was concerning the 'From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level mail domains are different' - does this have to do with the bounce and reply email domains not matching the sending domain? Those are both showing up as coming from the domain that was setup using the SAP - is there a way to override that so the bounce and reply addresses match the private domain we're sending from?